# golang interface compliance compile type check

Tags: pointers, interface, go

I see the following statements from camlistore(http://code.google.com/p/camlistore/source/browse/pkg/cacher/cacher.go).

```
var (
        _ blobref.StreamingFetcher = (*CachingFetcher)(nil)
        _ blobref.SeekFetcher      = (*CachingFetcher)(nil)
        _ blobref.StreamingFetcher = (*DiskCache)(nil)
        _ blobref.SeekFetcher      = (*DiskCache)(nil)
)
```

I understand that no variables are created and the statements ensure compiler checks that CachingFether implements public functions of StreamingFetcher and SeekFetcher. RHS portion uses a pointer constructor syntax with a nil parameter. What does this syntax mean in Go language ?

Comment: I'm curious as to why that check is necessary. It seems to me that if they ever actually /used/ those values, the compiler would do the check? The only explanation I can think of is that they use the `unsafe` package, and they are going to do non-checked operations that they want the compiler to check anyway. But they don't import `unsafe` in that file. Any ideas?

Comment: It's a static (compile time) check if the RHS type satisfies the LHS interface. With such check an accidental change to the RHS method set is immediately rejected by the compiler.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`(*T)(nil)` is a [Conversion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions). In this case it stands for a typed nil, ie. the same value which, for example

```
var p *T
```

has before assigning anything to it.

The standard syntax of a conversion is `T(expr)`, but the priority of the `*` would bind it wrongly in

```
*T(expr)
```

This syntax means dereferencing the return value of function `T` with one argument `expr`. That's why the conversion has an alternative syntax:

```
(T)(expr)
```

where `T` can of course be `*U`. Therefore

```
(*U)(expr)
```

is the generalized form of what you see in the Camlistore repository.