# Identifying the actual type being stored in a go interface

Tags: go, types, interface

In the following code

```
    var r io.Reader
    c, _ := net.Dial("tcp", ":8080")
    r = c 
    switch r.(type) {
    case io.Reader:
        fmt.Println("r implements the reader interface")
        // fallthrough
    case io.Writer:
        fmt.Println("r implements the writer interface")
    case net.Conn:
        fmt.Println("r implements the conn interface")
    }
```

the first `case` statement is the one that's always executed.

If I uncomment `fallthrough` the code does not compile given that `fallthrough` is not allowed in a type switch

If I am not wrong a `go` interface has 2 values:

- the actual TYPE (descriptor) stored in the interface (e.g. `io.Writer`, `io.Reader` etc)
- the value stored in it

Since `r` apparently satisfies all of the above `case` statements, what is the way of finding the exact type stored in `r`?

Is it only through reflection that this cone be done?

Comment: I'm confused. You've defined `r` as a value of type `io.Reader` -- why would you expect that its type match anything but `io.Reader`?

Comment: I am trying to get some more insights about the type switch functionality; and apparently `r` does match all of the above

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32113597/checking-of-variable-implements-interface-without-compiling

Answer (score 4):

The [type switch](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements) as well as the [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) may be used to check if an interface value holds a value of a concrete type (and at the same time extract a value of that concrete type). If the type you check (or type assert) is an interface type (and not a concrete type), the case will match (or the assertion will hold) if the concrete type implements the given interface type.

[`net.Conn`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Conn) is an interface that is a superset of both [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) and [`io.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer). If something implements `net.Conn`, it automatically implements `io.Reader` and `io.Writer` as well, so if you check `io.Reader` first, that will match (if the type also implements `net.Conn`).

If you want to use a type switch to check for implemented interfaces, check for `net.Conn` first, and if it's not implemented, list `io.Reader` and `io.Writer` later on.

```
switch r.(type) {
case net.Conn:
    fmt.Println("r implements the conn interface")
case io.Reader:
    fmt.Println("r implements the reader interface")
case io.Writer:
    fmt.Println("r implements the writer interface")
}
```

> If I am not wrong a go interface has 2 values:
>
> - the actual TYPE (descriptor) stored in the interface (e.g. io.Writer, io.Reader etc)
> - the value stored in it

You are not wrong but you miss a key point: the actual **concrete** type. `io.Conn` and `io.Reader` are not concrete types, they are inteface types.

An example *concrete* type that may be returned by `net.Dial()` is [`*net.TCPConn`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#TCPConn).

Comment: so in my code snippet, what is the __concrete__ type stored in `r`?

Comment: @pkaramol Most likely `*net.TCPConn`. Use `fmt.Printf("%T", r)` to see.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to find the concrete type of the value:

```
var r io.Reader
c, _ := net.Dial("tcp", ":8080")
r = c 
fmt.Printf("The type of r is %T\n", r)
```

The reflect package can also be used to find the concrete type:

```
t := reflect.TypeOf(r)
fmt.Println("The type of or is", t)
```

Use separate if statements to check support for each interface. A type switch cannot test for all interfaces because the switch continues on the the first type to match.

```
if _, ok := r.(io.Reader); ok {
    // we know this already because r is an io.Reader
    fmt.Println("r implements the reader interface")
}
if _, ok := r.(io.Writer); ok {
    fmt.Println("r implements the writer interface")
}
if _. ok := r.(net.Conn); ok {
    fmt.Println("r implements the conn interface")
}
```

We know that the conditions in all of the if statements evaluate to true because the value in `r` satisfies the `net.Conn` interface.