# usage of interface{} on a struct to check if it satisfies an interface in golang

Tags: go, interface

Given the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type work interface {
    filter() bool
}

type organ struct {
    name string
}

func (s *organ) filter () bool {
    return true;
}


func main() {
    kidney := &organ {
            name : "kidney",    
        }

    _, ok := interface{}(kidney).(work)
    fmt.Println(ok);
}
```

I did not fully get the following part:

```
_, ok := interface{}(kidney).(work)
```

It seems to me, it is converting struct to the `interface{}` type, which I understand, but why is it required to convert to an `interface{}` type to check if it satisfies another interface. More specifically, why the following code fails?

```
ok := kidney.(work)
```

with error

`invalid type assertion: kidney.(work) (non-interface type *organ on left)`

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Type assertions are for interface types only. Also, this check can be done at compile time with `var _ work = &organ{}`.

Comment: If you just have a variable of type "organ" you already know the type, so there's no need to assert that it's a worker (just call filter and if it's not a worker the build will fail). Casting a concrete type to an interface and then checking it is code smell in Go; there may be uses for it, but it's probably best if you let the compiler sort it out for you instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explanation of checking if value implements interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803654/explanation-of-checking-if-value-implements-interface)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TL;DR If you always know the concrete type (e.g., `kidney`), then you don't need a type assertion; just pass it into your `work` variable and carry on--the compiler will guarantee that `kidney` satisfies the `work` interface, otherwise your program won't compile.

The reason you must first convert the *concrete type* into an `interface{}` is because type assertions (i.e., *dynamic type checks*) only make sense between *dynamic types* (i.e., interfaces). It doesn't make sense to do a runtime type check on a thing the compiler can guarantee at compile time. Hopefully this makes sense?