# How to check if a value implements an interface

Tags: go

I want to compare my type by the specific way. For this purpose, I create the function `MyType.Same(other MyType) bool` for each type.

In some generic function, I want to check if the parameter has a function "Same" and invoke it if yes.

How can I do it in a generic way for different types?

```
type MyType struct {
   MyField string
   Id string // ignored by comparison
}

func (mt MyType) Same(other MyType) bool {
    return mt.MyField == other.MyField
}

// MyOtherType... Same(other MyOtherType)


type Comparator interface {
    Same(Camparator) bool // or Same(interface{}) bool
}

myType = new(MyType)
_, ok := reflect.ValueOf(myType).Interface().(Comparator) // ok - false

myOtherType = new(myOtherType)
_, ok := reflect.ValueOf(myOtherType).Interface().(Comparator) // ok - false
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explanation of checking if value implements interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803654/explanation-of-checking-if-value-implements-interface)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The types do not satisfy the `Comparator` interface.  The types have a `Same` method, but those methods do not have argument type `Comparator`.  The argument types must match to satisfy an interface.

Change the the methods and interface to take the same argument type. Use a type assertion to check that receiver and argument have the same type and to get argument as the receiver's type.

```
 type Comparator interface {
    Same(interface{}) bool
 }

func (mt MyType) Same(other interface{}) bool {
    mtOther, ok := other.(MyType)
    if !ok {
        return false
    }
    return return mt.MyField == mtOther.MyField
}
```

Use the following to compare two values:

```
func same(a, b interface{}) bool {
  c, ok := a.(Comparator)
  if !ok {
     return false
  }
  return c.Same(b)
}
```

If the types the application works with have the `Compare` method, then there's no need to declare the `Comparator` interface or use the `same` function in the previous snippet of code. For example, the `Comparator` interface is not required for the following:

```
var mt MyType
var other interface{}

eq := mt.Same(other)
```

Comment: This is the better answer, Savash. I will delete mine.

Comment: @TehSphinX,  your answer was very close and led me to the same solution that ThnderCat posted. Thanks!