# Why is a custom struct accepted in place of an error?

Tags: go, struct, types, error-handling

Learning Go and with reference to https://tour.golang.org/methods/20

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

type ErrNegativeSqrt float64 //This is the custom Struct

func (e ErrNegativeSqrt) Error() string { 
    return fmt.Sprintf("cannot Sqrt negative number: %g", float64(e))
}

func Sqrt(x float64) (float64, error) {  // Is error a type ?
    if(x < 0){
        return x, ErrNegativeSqrt(x) //Q1) If error is a type, How come  ErrNegativeSqrt(x) is of type error?
    }       
    z := float64(1.5)
    val := float64(0)
    for {
        z = z - (z*z-x)/(2*z)
        if math.Abs(val-z) < 1e-10 {
            break
        }
        val = z
    }
    return val, nil
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Sqrt(2))
    fmt.Println(Sqrt(-2))
}
```

Q2) Why does a call to fmt.Sprint(e) inside the Error method will send the program into an infinite loop?

Comment: Q2) the infinite recursion happens because `fmt` under the hood looks at the provided value and if that value implements a specific interface it will invoke its primary method, in this case the `Error` method of the `error` interface, but also types implementing the `Stringer` interface are susceptible to this. Therefore it is important in these kinds of methods, if they want to pass the receiver to `fmt`, to convert the receiver to a type that doesn't implement those interfaces, like you see in the example with `float64(e)`.

Comment: Your title asked about a custom struct, but your example doesn't even use a strict. It's a float64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go's `interface` is tricky.  It takes some experimenting with it to get a good feel for how to use it.  That's why the tutorial you're working with has you write things using it: you have to actually use it for a while before you can get to the point where you understand how to use it. :-)

It's worth correcting some nits here though:

> ```
> type ErrNegativeSqrt float64 //This is the custom Struct
> ```

This is not a `struct` type.  `float64` itself is a predeclared *numeric type*, [as defined here in the Go reference](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types):

> A *numeric type* represents sets of integer or floating-point values. The predeclared architecture-independent numeric types are: [various entries snipped out here]
>
> ```
> float64     the set of all IEEE-754 64-bit floating-point numbers
> ```

Your `type` declaration here creates a new type named `ErrNegativeSqrt` that has `float64` as its *underlying type*; see [the **Types** section](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types).

A type—any type, whether `struct` or not—either *implements* an interface type, or does not.  An interface type is, well, complicated; see [the **Interface types** section](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types) for the full picture.  Go's `error` is a predeclared interface type, as defined by [the **Errors** section](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Errors):

> The predeclared type `error` is defined as
>
> ```
> type error interface {
>     Error() string
> }
> ```

This means that whenever you define your own type *UserT*, if you add a line like this:

```
func (varname UserT) Error() string {
    // return some string here
}
```

your defined type *UserT* now *implements the error interface*.  As such, you can *convert* any value of type *UserT* to `error` via simple assignment.  See [the **Assignability** section](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability), which includes:

> A value `x` is *assignable* to a variable of type `T`... if one of the following conditions applies: [some bullet items snipped]
>
> - `T` is an interface type and `x` implements `T`

We just saw that `error` is an interface type.  So, if some situation calls for a variable of type `error`, and you have some existing value `x` of type `UserT` where `UserT` has a method `Error() string`, you can assign that value `x` into the variable of type `error`.  That is, given `ErrNegativeSqrt` set up as you did, and:

```
var x ErrNegativeSqrt
// set `x` to some valid value

// and:
var e error
```

then:

```
e = x
```

is valid and assigns `x` into `e`, though the *type* of *`e` itself* is an interface type, rather than `ErrNegativeSqrt`.

When you stuff a copy of the value of `x` *into* `e` like this, the compiler actually sets up *two* things inside `e`.  In other words, `e` acts a lot like a two-element array, or a `struct` with two fields, except that you can't access the two fields with subscripts or `.field` type spellings.

One of these two values—the first half of `e`'s value—is `x`'s *concrete type*.  The other of these two values is `x`'s actual value, copied into the other half of `e`.

In other words, the compiler turns:

```
e = x
```

into the rough equivalent of:

```
e.value = x
e.type = ErrNegativeSqrt
```

except, again, for the fact that you can't actually *write* `e.type` and `e.value`.  The compiler does the two-part-izing *for* you, automatically.

[You should have already seen how you can pick apart the two parts of things stored into `e` if necessary.](https://tour.golang.org/methods/11)  It's often *not* necessary, especially if the interface is well designed.  But it's worth backtracking to these earlier sections of the Tour after experimenting with error returns in [#20](https://tour.golang.org/methods/20).

Comment: this is a continuation to understand internal representation of an interface value https://www.tapirgames.com/blog/golang-interface-implementation

Comment: @torek Thank you very much for writing a detailed answer which really helps newbies like me. Few questions
1) Are these the only 8 basic (in-built in language) types in Golang?
2) What is meant by literal? I still can't wrap my head around literals. When they say String literal, map literal what are they?

Comment: @torek That behind the scenes compiler thing e = x explanation is beyond words. How do you guys learn all these?

Comment: I'm not sure how you are counting 8 in-built types. The spec (https://golang.org/ref/spec) calls out `bool` + 17 numeric types + plus `string`. Array, slice, struct, pointer, function, and interface types are built atop these, so I'd perhaps count 19 of these primitive types. It's true that some of the numeric types have the same underlying type (`int` matches, underneath, `int32` or `int64` for instance) but these are still different. However, `byte` and `rune` are type *aliases* so we can subtract 2 from the 19 to get 17. But the exact number isn't all that important.

Comment: As for literals, Go's are pretty conventional: they're defined starting at https://golang.org/ref/spec#Integer_literals going down through https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals. What are unusual in Go are *constants* (https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants) which may be untyped.

Comment: To learn these, it helps to go through the Go Tour *more than once*. I've found that doing these information-dense tutorials at least twice, and sometimes three times, is wise: you miss a lot of things on the first pass, especially if you are used to learning from Huge Books Of Everything. Then, having done that, read through the entire Go spec (probably also two or three times, over the course of a month or more). Not everything will stick, but—at least for me—I'll remember: *oh, there was something in the spec about ____*.

Comment: At this point—having read the spec at least twice, or maybe even during your second pass through it—you're ready to look at things like @mh-cbon's link above, which talks about how the compiler and runtime conspire to *look up* methods when using interfaces and stuff like `reflect`. This sort of thing *isn't* part of the spec, on purpose, so that the compiler and runtime people can move on to a newer and more efficient conspiracy someday, if they can think of one.

Answer (score 1):

Error is an interface that defines an `Error() string` method. If your error implements that interface it is fine.

```
func (e ErrNegativeSqrt) Error() string { 
    return fmt.Sprintf("cannot Sqrt negative number: %g", float64(e))
}
```

And that code exactly does it. Now your `ErrNegativeSqrt` type implements error interface.

```
if(x < 0){
        return x, ErrNegativeSqrt(x) // totally fine.
    }
```

Documentation for [error](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#error)

Comment: So basically when I read Go code, how can I identify that there is an interface which is being implemented here?

Comment: @sofs1 Go has no implict type conversion, so if you find the required type is not the same of the provided type, then it is either an interface implemented, or in a rare case, a type alias.

Comment: @sofs1 Interface implementation checked in the compile time. But you have the option check that explicitly as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803654/explanation-of-checking-if-value-implements-interface)