# How to handle DB connection in Go when using Repository pattern?

Tags: sql, go, interface, nosql, repository-pattern

Let's assume I have a very simple repository interface that only reads from target database:

```
type UserRepository interface {
    read(ctx context.Context, id WHAT_TYPE_I_SHOULD_USE_HERE) models.User
}
```

**NOTE:** note that in id parameter I do not have any idea what to user as id type as id in `MongoDB` is `ObjectId` and in schema based DBs it might be a `UUID` field. My primary database is MongoDB if it helps, but I might switch to schema-based DBs.

Now I have a `MongoDBRepository` struct that has `read()` attached to it:

```
type MongoDBRepository struct {
}

func (mo MongoDBRepository) read(ctx context.Context, id primitive.ObjectID) {
    fmt.Printf("read user %s from MongoDB", id)
}
```

I have a method that connects to MongoDB:

```
func ConnectMongoDB() (*mongo.Client, context.CancelFunc) {
    client, err := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI(configs.MongoURI()))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)

    err = client.Connect(ctx)

    err = client.Ping(ctx, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Print("Successfully connected to MongoDB!")

    return client, cancel
}
```

Now as interface is implemented we can have a similar repository for `MySQL`/`PostgreSQL` and also `ConnectMySQL`/`ConnectPostgreSQL`.

The issue I have is in my main function how should I handle connecting to my current database repository and how to use it in my controllers to read or update a document/record?

When I pass my connection to a controller method its type is set to `*mongo.Client` how can I abstract it away so my controller method that gets DB connection is not bound to target DB type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how should I handle connecting to my current database repository and
> how to use it in my controllers to read or update a document/record

I am always checking provider documentation to get a hint for that question.

After quick search, I found what I need in [Github](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/blob/master/mongo/client.go#L50-L51):

```
// Client is a handle representing a pool of connections to a MongoDB deployment. It is safe for concurrent use by
// multiple goroutines.
```

Client is thread safe and represent not a single connection but a connection pool. That means that I can share a single Client instance among multiple instances of Controllers/Repositories, and the client can handle that.

Starting with Repositories. We need to inject Client:

```
type MongoDBRepository struct {
   Client mongo.Client
}
```

With current design, repository only contain thread safe members, so it is inherently thread safe.

This is the code to create a Repository in app start code:

```
repo := &MongoDBRepository{Client: client}
```

In controller, we define `Repository` as interface type, but we will inject `MongoDBRepository` struct:

```
// Controller Code
type UserController struct {
   Repo UserRepository
}
```

Controllers' initiation code also should happen on application star:

```
// App start 
controller := &UserController{Repo: repo}
```

To deal with db specific types (`id WHAT_TYPE_I_SHOULD_USE_HERE`), you need to implement them  as [Generics](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/generics). It could make your Controller code a quite complicated. Consider hiding that complexity inside a Repository and exposing something simple like string or uuid.

With that approach, you easily can switch between different DBs. All you need to change is app initialization ([Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/)) without changing controllers code.

P.S. Multiple databases support is quite expensive. We already faced an issue with ID types. In the future, you should be ready to [stop using any DB specific features and use only features available across all the databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_selection#Lowest_common_denominator_strategy). DB transactions is one of the great SQL features that is not available in Mongo. Weight pros and cons before you are fully committed to multiple DB types.

Update:

1. Implement controller as struct with ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) method.
2. Create instance if that struct in `main.go` as described above.
3. integrate that struct into router using `router.Handle` instead of `router.HandleFunc`

With struct, you should have better control for Controller dependencies lifecycle.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have created a `MongoDBRepository` and passed it to my controller, but I get type mismatch: `Cannot use 'repo' (type *helpers.MongoDBRepository) as the type helpers.UserRepository`.  In my user controller I have `func CreateUser(repo helpers.UserRepository) http.HandlerFunc {}`. When you say injecting `MongoDBRepository`, how you accomplish that?

Comment: Make sure repo struct and interface match all used functions.  In posted code `UserRepository ` returns `models.User`. Do the same in `func (mo MongoDBRepository) read`. Check https://betterprogramming.pub/a-comprehensive-guide-to-interfaces-in-go-6a945b795db

Comment: I posted an update to answer.

Comment: Check that  MongoDBRepository implements  helpers.UserRepository https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803654/explanation-of-checking-if-value-implements-interface