# Why declare like "var _ I = T{}" and "var _ I = &T{}" continuously?

Tags: go, registry, docker

When I read a copy of the docker/distribution source code, I find there are variables declared which make me quite confused.
[The code is](https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/65b0d73cb749fd9757352f472e399024f1c597df/registry/storage/driver/fileinfo.go#L55-56):

```
var _ FileInfo = FileInfoInternal{}
var _ FileInfo = &FileInfoInternal{}
```

I don't know what the declare mean, and hope to get some help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ensure a type implements an interface at compile time in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60663003)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From the [FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq#guarantee_satisfies_interface):

> You can ask the compiler to check that the type T implements the
>   interface I by attempting an assignment:
>
> ```
> type T struct{} 
> var _ I = T{}   // Verify that T implements I.
> ```

In this case the blank identifier _ stands for the variable name which is not needed here (and thus prevents a "declared but not used" error).

And more general from the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments):

> The blank identifier provides a way to ignore right-hand side values
>   in an assignment:
>
> ```
> _ = x       // evaluate x but ignore it 
> x, _ = f()  // evaluate f() but ignore second result value
> ```

By testing both `FileInfoInternal{}` and `&FileInfoInternal{}` you check if the interface is implemented with a value receiver. A value receiver will accept both a value and a pointer whereas the pointer receiver will only work with a pointer and the first assignment by value will fail.

The second test with `&FileInfoInternal{}` is not actually needed (as confirmed by the author in the comments) since the first test will pass with a value receiver and fail with a pointer received. Thus the second test is redundant.

[This](http://jordanorelli.com/post/32665860244/how-to-use-interfaces-in-go) is an excellent article that explains the difference between value and pointer receivers and how they are used very well.

Comment: To avoid confusion I like to include a comment like `// Verify FileInfoInternal implements os.FileInfo` right above such variables. Personally I also stick those in `_test.go` files since I consider them a test like any other.

Comment: Author here. Looking at this, I cannot recall why I put both declarations. The value assertion should be sufficient.

We've been using these as annotations next to declarations for clarity in the following implementation. I've seen the convention of putting in the `_test.go` files and have accepted contributions in that manner.

Answer (score 1):

`FileInfo` is an [interface](https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/master/registry/storage/driver/fileinfo.go#L7) and the code checks whether `FileInfoInternal` [implements](https://golang.org/doc/faq#guarantee_satisfies_interface) this interface.

Comment: But why should check both FileInfoInternal and &FileInfoInternal?

Comment: @JCheng the second part is not clear to me and I wait by myself to see the answer for this one.