# What does `(*RawMessage)(nil)` mean?

Tags: go

The section [Interface checks from Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#blank_implements) recommends

```
var _ json.Marshaler = (*RawMessage)(nil)
```

as a compile-time check that `RawMessage` implements `Marshaler`.

I get how the assignment does the type check but what does the right side actually mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ensure a type implements an interface at compile time in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60663003)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. It creates a new `*RawMessage` (pointer to `RawMessage`) that is `nil` by casting `nil` to `*RawMessage`. I would have expected

```
*RawMessage(nil)
```

but **that doesn't work** because the <strike>cast</strike> conversion seems to take precedence over the pointer operator, so it would become a dereference.

Comment: See here for conversion details:
https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions